# How to increase a javascript marquee to the size of the website?

Tags: javascript, css, height, css-position, marquee

I have a vertical javascript marquee on my website (http://blogandthecity.net).  I want it to be stuck at the screen. I think it is called "fixed". Right now the marquee stops at a certain point, but I want it to be the size of the whole screen/website.

I think there are two options: 
**1.** make the marquee as long as possible (However some webpages are longer than others. And I don't know how I can make the marquee longer. I already tried some things) 
**2.** make the position fixed. (I tried to put "position: fixed" in the code, but the result is that the marquee doesn't scroll anymore. So the movement stops. And the marquee doesn't fit the screen either..)

Do you know how I can solve this problem? If you need the css style, I will put it here too.

Below the code (I excluded the text part):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://blogandthecity.net/js/marquee-packed.js" ></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    //create instance and call method horizontal for horizontal scrolling  
   var horizontal = new marquee("marquee").horizontal(  
   {  
    step:1, //how many pixels to move per interval (default: 1)  
    interval: 40, //how often to move pixels in miliseconds (default: 10)  
    stop_on_hover: true, //should marquee stop on mouse hover (default: true)  
    backwards: false, //rotate elements in opposite direction  
});
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
     //create instance and call method horizontal for horizontal scrolling  
    var horizontal = new marquee("marquee2").horizontal(  
{  
    step:1, //how many pixels to move per interval (default: 1)  
    interval: 40, //how often to move pixels in miliseconds (default: 10)  
    stop_on_hover: true, //should marquee stop on mouse hover (default: true)  
    backwards: false, //rotate elements in opposite direction  
});
```

Comment: A marquee? I seem to have somehow traveled back in time... http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#time-limits

Comment: No. Marquees should never be used, they go against the W3C accessibility guidelines (see the link in my above comment).

Comment: Woww soo the marquee on my website (http://blogandthecity.net) is illegal?! Wow how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @user1861212, The marquee effect on that site has nothing to do with content, and is just a visual gimmick.  It's fine to do something like that, as it doesn't add anything to the content of the site.  Someone blind won't care that random country names are floating vertically on that site.

Comment: I understand it :) Thanks! Does anybody has a solution to fixe the marquee?

Answer (score 0):

It is called position:fixed; Below the css for your marquees scrolling down and being full screen. You may need to go jQuery since they are styled inline (or modify the html?)

```
#marquee, #marquee2 {
position:fixed;
}

#marquee {
margin-top:140px;
}

#marquee2 {
margin-left:-520px;
}
```